# Pygame not transitioning to the next image

Tags: python, pygame

I am working on my first python project. I have some buttons, 'Yes' and 'No' after the initial question of "do you want to play?". When I press no it closes the game. When I click yes, I'd like it for it to jump to the next function where it displays the text "so you've decided to play", and although I can see it jump to the next text for a little bit, it quickly switches back to the previous question and buttons of "Do you wish to play?" with the Yes and No buttons. How can I fix this? I've tried to order pygame.display.update() in different ways but so far no luck. Any help would be appreciated, thanks guys. Here is my code:

```
import pygame
pygame.init()

win=pygame.display.set_mode((800,700))
win.fill((255,255,255))
our_game_display=pygame.Surface((800,700))
font_name = pygame.font.get_default_font()
class button():
    def __init__(self, color, x, y, width, height, text=''):
        self.color = color
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.width = width
        self.height = height
        self.text = text

    def draw(self, win, outline=None):
        # Call this method to draw the button on the screen
        if outline:
            pygame.draw.rect(win, outline, (self.x - 2, self.y - 2, self.width + 4, self.height + 4), 0)

        pygame.draw.rect(win, self.color, (self.x, self.y, self.width, self.height), 0)

        if self.text != '':
            font = pygame.font.SysFont('comicsans', 60)
            text = font.render(self.text, 1, (255, 255, 255))
            win.blit(text, (
                self.x + (self.width / 2 - text.get_width() / 2), self.y + (self.height / 2 - text.get_height() / 2)))

    def isOver(self, pos):
        # Pos is the mouse position or a tuple of (x,y) coordinates
        if pos[0] > self.x and pos[0] < self.x + self.width:
            if pos[1] > self.y and pos[1] < self.y + self.height:
                return True

        return False
def yes_no_choice():
    #win.fill((0,0,0))
    YesButton.draw(win,(255,255,255))
    NoButton.draw(win,(255,255,255))

def draw_text(text, size, x, y):
        pygame.font.init()
        font = pygame.font.Font(font_name, size)
        text_surface = font.render(text, True, (255,255,255))
        text_rect = text_surface.get_rect()
        text_rect.center = (x, y)
        our_game_display.blit(text_surface, text_rect)
def beginning_question():
    our_game_display.fill((0, 0, 0))
    draw_text('The story of this game depends on your choices. Do you wish to play?', 20, 800 / 2, 700 / 2 - 100)
    win.blit(our_game_display, (0, 0))
    yes_no_choice()

    pygame.display.update()

def begin_game():
    our_game_display.fill((0,0,0))
    draw_text("So you've decided to play...very well.", 20, 800 / 2, 700 / 2 - 100)
    win.blit(our_game_display,(0,0))
    pygame.display.update()

#game loop
running = True
YesButton=button((0,0,0),100,500,250,100,'Yes')
NoButton=button((0,0,0),450,500,250,100,'No')

while running:

    beginning_question()
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        pos=pygame.mouse.get_pos()

        if event.type==pygame.QUIT:
            running = False
            pygame.quit()
            quit()

        if event.type==pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            if YesButton.isOver(pos):
                begin_game()
            if NoButton.isOver(pos):
                running=False
                pygame.quit()
                quit()

        if event.type==pygame.MOUSEMOTION:
            if YesButton.isOver(pos):
                YesButton.color=(0,0,139)
            elif NoButton.isOver(pos):
                NoButton.color=(0,0,139)
            else:
                YesButton.color=(0,0,0)
                NoButton.color=(0,0,0)
```

Comment: that's because your `while` loops is returning you to `beginning_question()`. You need to keep the state of your game

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why it only flashes for a second and then switches back is because the drawing for the "So you've decided to play" only happens in frames where you click the yes button. It should happen continuously after you hit the yest button. Here is one potential solution:

Have a boolean variable game_begun to keep track of whether the game has begun or not (initially false):

```
YesButton = button((0, 0, 0), 100, 500, 250, 100, 'Yes')
NoButton = button((0, 0, 0), 450, 500, 250, 100, 'No')
game_begun = False # New variable
```

After the user clicks the yes button, set that variable to true:

```
if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
    if YesButton.isOver(pos):
        game_begun = True
    if NoButton.isOver(pos):
        running = False
        pygame.quit()
        quit()
```

Finally, in the game loop (not the event loop), have a condition to check if the game has begun, and if so, then call the begin_game function. If not, then draw the beginning question:

```
if game_begun:
    begin_game()
else:
    beginning_question()
```

This might not be the absolute best solution, but it should suffice for your first python project. As you add more states to your game, you should use a string variable to keep track of you game state instead of a boolean. Happy coding!